# Portfolio page Bootstrap sections

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is the right place to ask the question. Trying to make a portfolio page and I want my header section to fill the screen and then only as you scroll, does the next section appear.

like on this webpage https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

What css is used to make it happen, cannot figure it out -_-

I have tried looking into the html/css of the theme but cannot find what i'm looking for.

May be it has something to do with positions.

Answer (score 1):

U want the nav to be fixed at the top?

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>`

This is what u need. Check [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) components for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed nav-bar. Look and try out this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>

</body>
</html>
```